# c# Mover imagem sem rastro

Tags: c#, picturebox

Estou movendo uma picturebox por cima de outra com mouse. Porém ela fica deixando um rastro por trás quando mexo o mouse, o rastro some logo em seguida, mas, existe um jeito de remover isso?

Tentei tirar o `refresh()` quando a imagem move, tira o rastro mas ela trava demais, mexe muito lenta, fica dando trancos.

Aqui o código:

```
private void picImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (picImage.Image == null)
            return;

        if(act)
        UpdateZoomedImage(e);

       picZoom.Location = new Point(e.X+40, e.Y+40);
       picZoom.Refresh();
    }
```

codigo do Zoom:

```
private void UpdateZoomedImage(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Calculate the width and height of the portion of the image we want
        // to show in the picZoom picturebox. This value changes when the zoom
        // factor is changed.
        int zoomWidth = picZoom.Width / _ZoomFactor;
        int zoomHeight = picZoom.Height / _ZoomFactor;

        // Calculate the horizontal and vertical midpoints for the crosshair
        // cursor and correct centering of the new image
        int halfWidth = zoomWidth / 2;
        int halfHeight = zoomHeight / 2;

        // Create a new temporary bitmap to fit inside the picZoom picturebox
        Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(zoomWidth, zoomHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // Create a temporary Graphics object to work on the bitmap
        Graphics bmGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);

        // Clear the bitmap with the selected backcolor
        bmGraphics.Clear(_BackColor);

        // Set the interpolation mode
        bmGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the portion of the main image onto the bitmap
        // The target rectangle is already known now.
        // Here the mouse position of the cursor on the main image is used to
        // cut out a portion of the main image.
        bmGraphics.DrawImage(picImage.Image,
                             new Rectangle(0, 0, zoomWidth, zoomHeight),
                             new Rectangle(e.X - halfWidth, e.Y - halfHeight, zoomWidth, zoomHeight),
                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Draw the bitmap on the picZoom picturebox
        picZoom.Image = tempBitmap;

        // Draw a crosshair on the bitmap to simulate the cursor position
        bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight - 4, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight - 1);
        bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight + 6, halfWidth + 1, halfHeight + 3);
        bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth - 4, halfHeight + 1, halfWidth - 1, halfHeight + 1);
        bmGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, halfWidth + 6, halfHeight + 1, halfWidth + 3, halfHeight + 1);

        // Dispose of the Graphics object
        bmGraphics.Dispose();

        // Refresh the picZoom picturebox to reflect the changes
        picZoom.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: qual o código do seu UpdateZoomedImage ?

Comment: Editei o post com o código.

Comment: acredito que o problema seja, que a cada ponto movido do mouse, você redesenha a imagem completamente, não sei se funciona, mas tenta chamar o método `this.SuspendLayout();` do form, antes de desenhar, e depois que estiver pronto, o `this.ResumeLayout();`. Se não funcionar, colocaria um timer pra atrasar o processo de desenho, só executando-o uma vez, ao final do movimento.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, com timer funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: que beleza! coloquei como resposta, se quiser marcar e fechar a questão =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja, que a cada ponto movido do mouse, você redesenha a imagem completamente, eu colocaria um `Timer` pra atrasar o processo de desenho, só executando-o uma vez, ao final do movimento.